# What driver can I use for a Xerox Workcentre 7535 printer?

Tags: printing, xerox

The Ubuntu drivers do not contain a driver for the **Workcentre 7535** and the drivers from the [Xerox homepage](https://www.support.xerox.com/en-us/product/workcentre-7545-7556/downloads?platform=linux&product=&category=&language=en&attributeId=) don't contain a ppd for the model either.

With a postscript driver from another model I can print in black & white, but where can I get a driver that supports color printing (and if possible the features of the finisher unit of the printer)?

Comment: Only from the vendor. Contact them and ask,

Comment: @David The vendor homepage for the product drivers is linked in the question. Their response was not helpful in this case. So I wonder if either someone knows other downloads or a compatible model that has a driver.